# Can't use dask to open tiff read with tifffile

Tags: python, dask, tiff, zarr

I have a TIFF image that I would like to open and process using dask. This is the code that I am currently using

```
import dask.array as da
from tifffile import imread
import zarr

img_path = '/path/to/tiff.ndpi'
img = imread(img_path, aszarr=True)
img = zarr.open(img)
img = da.from_zarr(img[0])
img_means = da.mean(img, axis=(0, 1)).compute()
```

I am trying to access the lowest resolution image from the TIFF. When I run this I get an error stating

> TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object

and then another error stating

> TypeError: ('Could not serialize object of type HighLevelGraph', ...

How can I open a tiff image using imread from tiffile and directly use it as a dask array?

Comment: See https://forum.image.sc/t/error-loading-tiff-into-dask/94057/2